# Find all integers n such that n−2014 and n+ 2014 are both triangular numbers.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

I came across this problem when searching for triangular numbers questions.

I know that I need to use the equation, $$\frac {n(n+1)}{2} $$
but I don't know how to apply it to this problem.

Comment: You are looking for numbers $x$ such that both $x-2014 = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x+2014 = \frac{m(m+1)}{2}$ for some $m \in \mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one approach: If $n - 2014$ is a triangular number, then

$$n = \frac{k(k + 1)}{2} + 2014$$

for some integer $k$. Since $n + 2014$ is also a triangular number,

$$n = \frac{l(l + 1)}{2} - 2014$$

for some integer $l$. It follows that

$$k(k + 1) + 4028 = l (l + 1) - 4028$$

Rearranging this, we get

$$l^2 + l - k^2 - k = 8056$$
Now since $l^2 - k^2$ is a difference of squares, we can factor the left-hand side as

\begin{align*}
2^3 \cdot 19 \cdot 53 = 8056 = (l - k)(l + k) + (l - k) = (l - k)(l + k + 1)
\end{align*}

Hence $l - k$ must be one of the (exactly) $4 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 = 16$ divisors of $8056$, as must $l + k + 1$. This is extremely limiting.

Comment: The choice is reduced quite a bit when you observe that $l + k + 1$ and $l - k$ must have different parity, and if you are only concerned with positive triangular numbers, that $l - k < l + k + 1$.